# Writing Hamiltonian matrix elements for a two non-interacting particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, two-level-system

Let's say I have two non-interacting particles in the classic infinite well boxes of length L. I know the total energy is given by: $$E_{n_1,n_2}=\dfrac{\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}(n_1^2+n_2^2)$$
where n_1,n_2=1,2,3,...

Usually when I try to find the Hamiltonian matrix elements (say for the first two levels), I just compute the inner product $\langle i|H|j \rangle=E_{i}\delta_{i,j}$ where $i$ and $j$ correspond to the eigenstates and the row and column of our matrix. But with for a two particle system, I'm not sure how to do this. I guess my confusion is what is considered to be the '1st state' of a two particle system and so on. I tried searching about this online, and I'm seeing things such as tensor products, which we did not touch on at all in class and I'm confident with where we are going, we won't be doing that at all.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases the notation has to adapt to multiple-particle states. More precisely, the Hamiltonian is split as
\begin{equation}
H= H_1 \otimes 1_2 + 1_1 \otimes H_2 \, ,
\end{equation}
and the eigenstates as
\begin{equation}
|n_1,n_2\rangle = |n_1\rangle \otimes |n_2\rangle \, .
\end{equation}
So that we have
\begin{eqnarray}
H \, |n_1,n_2\rangle &=& \left( H_1 \otimes 1_2 + 1_1 \otimes H_2 \right) |n_1\rangle \otimes |n_2\rangle
\\
&=&  H_1 \, |n1\rangle \otimes 1_2 \, |n_2\rangle + 1_1 \, |n_1\rangle \otimes H_2 \, |n_2\rangle  
\\
&=&  E_{n_1} \, |n_1\rangle \otimes |n_2\rangle + E_{n_2} \, |n_1\rangle \otimes |n_2\rangle
\\
&=& \left( E_{n_1} + E_{n_2} \right) \, |n_1,n_2\rangle 
\\
&=& E_{n_1,n_2} \, |n_1,n_2\rangle \, .
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, $\langle m_1,m_2| \, H \, |n_1,n_2\rangle \, = \, E_{n_1,n_2}  \, \langle m_1,m_2|n_1,n_2\rangle \, = \,  E_{n_1,n_2} \, \delta_{n_1,m_1} \, \delta_{n_2,m_2} \,$ .